# Getting error while parsing string value by SimpleDateFormat .parse()

Tags: java, datetime

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateExample {

public static SimpleDateFormat TIMEZONE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

private static final SimpleDateFormat[] DATE_FORMATS = 
{
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"),
    TIMEZONE_DATE_FORMAT,
};

public static void main(String[] args){

    for(SimpleDateFormat format : DATE_FORMATS){

        try {
            Date date = format.parse("1377154948450");
            System.out.println("Date: "+ date.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}

}
```

Now the String value in parse method is what am getting from a method call and I can't change that. While running this code am getting the Exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1377154948450"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: This question would be more suitable for SO. Code Review is about finding the "best" way to do something, not troubleshoot errors.

Comment: Your error pretty much tells it. `Unparseable date`. So try to give a proper date string to format.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a Date object from a timestamp for which you can just use new Date(1377154948450) - note the long value, not String. SimpleDateFormat works when converting to/from formatted Strings. Agree that this is the wrong forum though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because none of your formats matches the string.

You can try

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong("1377154948450"));
```